# Double authentication issue for REST web service deployed in WebLogic

Tags: java, java-ee-6, weblogic11g, basic-authentication

I have a restful web service which is protected using `HTTP Basic` authentication with `LDAP` provider.

After deploying the application to WebLogic, it prompts for authentication twice upon invocation.

First by Spring Security Then by WebLogic Server.

Further investigation on the subject reveals that `client requests that use HTTP BASIC authentication must pass WebLogic Server authentication, even if access control is not enabled on the target resource.`

As an option (provided in the answer), WebLogic's authentication can be disabled through the following configuration in **config.xml**:

```
<enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>false</enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>
```

But it will affect all the other applications deployed in the same domain. And I want this for a specific app only.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Try disabling WebLogic's authentication in `config.xml`:

```
<enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>false</enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>
```

See e.g.

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/upgrade/compat.html#wp1120669

So you can turn this on or off on a per-domain basis. If you need to target a specific app, consider placing that app in a dedicated domain.

Comment: Thank you willie, but this will disable weblogic basic auth for all the other applications as well deployed in the same container.

Comment: actually i do not want to disable the weblogic auth for all but for a specific app only.

Comment: From the links I provided, it sounds like an all-or-nothing affair. So you might need to create a dedicated WebLogic domain for the app in question. At any rate please update your question to indicate this additional constraint.

Answer (score 3):

Workaround, add another auth-method in the web.xml:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

Weblogic's basic-auth prompt won't show, only yours.

source: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/35977-weblogic-9x-10x-double-prompt-for-login-basic-auth-simple

Answer (score 1):

Started working after adding below configuration. But required to add new user in weblogic console or we can use default user.

Added below configuration in WEB-INF\web.xml file

```
  <security-constraint>
    <display-name>Secure REST Area</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secure REST</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>default</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>Admin</role-name>
</security-role>
```

created weblogic descriptor file in WEB-INF\weblogic.xml and added below configuration.

```
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <security-role-assignment>
     <role-name>Admin</role-name>
     <!-- <principal-name>Administrators</principal-name>-->
     <externally-defined/>
 </security-role-assignment>
```